# How to get around a NumPy error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, numpy

The below code is being used to analysis a csv file and at the moment im trying to remove the columns of the array which are not in my check_list. This only checks the first row and if the first row of the particular column doesnt belong to the check_list it removes the entire column. But this error keeps getting thrown and not sure how to avoid it.

```py
import numpy as np
def load_metrics(filename):
    """opens a csv file and returns stuff"""
    check_list = ["created_at","tweet_ID","valence_intensity","anger_intensity","fear_intensity","sadness_intensity","joy_intensity","sentiment_category","emotion_category"]
    file=open(filename)
    data = []
    for lin in file:
        lin = lin.strip()
        lin = lin.split(",")
        data.append(lin)
    for col in range(len(data[0])):
        if np.any(data[0][col] not in check_list) == True:
            data[0]= np.delete(np.array(data), col, 1)
        print(col)
    return np.array(data)
```

The below test is being used on the code too:

```
data = load_metrics("covid_sentiment_metrics.csv")
print(data[0])
```

Test results:

```
['created_at' 'tweet_ID' 'valence_intensity' 'anger_intensity'
 'fear_intensity' 'sadness_intensity' 'joy_intensity' 'sentiment_category'
 'emotion_category']
```

Comment: I don't know what causes your error, but maybe instead of deleting the columns you don't want, try collecting the columns you do want.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your source file (in **text** form, not very long). Please also state which line of your code causes this error.

Comment: This is row 1 after the first for loop

Comment: ['created_at', 'tweet_ID', 'text', 'screen_name', 'followers', 'friends', 'user_ID', 'valence_inten
sity', 'anger_intensity', 'fear_intensity', 'sadness_intensity', 'joy_intensity', 'sentiment_categor
y', 'emotion_category', 'country_region']

Comment: And the line causing the error is the "if" statement under the second for loop

Comment: You can't do an array test in an `if`  Study that `np.any(data[0][col] not in check_list)`.  Is an array?

Answer (score 0):

Change your *load_metrics* function to:

```
def load_metrics(filename):
    check_list = ["created_at","tweet_ID","valence_intensity","anger_intensity",
        "fear_intensity","sadness_intensity","joy_intensity","sentiment_category",
        "emotion_category"]
    data = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for lin in file:
            lin = lin.strip()
            lin = lin.split(",")
            data.append(lin)
    arr = np.array(data)
    colFilter = []
    for col in arr[0]:
        colFilter.append(col in check_list)
    return arr[:, colFilter]
```

I introduced the following corrections:

1. Use *with* to automatically close the input file (your code fails to close it).
2. Create a "full" *Numpy* array (all columns) after the data has been read.
3. Compute *colFilter* list - which columns are in *check_list*.
4. Return only filtered columns.

Answer (score 0):

### Read columns by checklist

This code does not include checks related to reading a file or a broken data structure, so that the main idea is more or less clear. So, here I assume that a csv-file exists and has at least 2 lines:

```py
import numpy as np

def load_metrics(filename, check_list):
    """open a csv file and return data as numpy.array
       with columns from a check list"""
    data = []
    with open(filename) as file:
        headers = file.readline().rstrip("\n").split(",")
        for line in file:
            data.append(line.rstrip("\n").split(","))
    col_to_remove = []
    for col in reversed(range(len(headers))):
        if headers[col] not in check_list:
            col_to_remove.append(col)
            headers.pop(col)
    data = np.delete(np.array(data), col_to_remove, 1)
    return data, headers
```

Quick testing:

```py
test_data = """\
hello,some,other,world
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
"""

with open("test.csv",'w') as f:
    f.write(test_data) 

check_list = ["hello","world"]
d, h = load_metrics("test.csv", check_list)
print(d, h)
```

Expected output:

```
[['1' '4']
 ['5' '8']] ['hello', 'world']
```

Some details:

- Instead of `np.any(data[0][col] not in check_list) == True` would be enough `data[0][col] not in check_list`
- Stripping with default parameters is not good as far as you can delete meaningful spaces.
- Do not delete anything while looping forward. But we can do it (with some reservations) while looping backward.
- `check_list` is better as a parameter.
- Separate data and headers as they may have different types.
- In your case it is better to use `pandas.read_csv`, see the picture below.

[image]